# Project a piece of image cut by N-vertex shape to a different N-vertex shape

Tags: algorithms, image-manipulation, geometry, image, image-processing

I have an N-vertex shape that I cut out from an image, and I want to project it onto another shape with the same amount of vertices, but different. So, the image will get changed inside the projection. Are there any known algorithms to do this?

Also:

- I know that the requirement "to project" a shape onto another shape could be rather vague in terms what transformations to choose to perform on the deformed image, or what to do in the case of the pixel information loss or the need to synthesize the pixel data, but I would appreciate any ideas along these lines
- If N-vertex is a too hard case, then what if N=4, i.e. the shape is a quad?

Comment: Provided that both 4-vertex shapes are convex, I'd split both to two triangles, and mapping between contents of two triangles is more or less obvious.

Comment: @9000 actually that is what I am doing right now. I have decided to retrieve the resulting image by projecting it on a 3D mesh with an OpenGL 3D engine, simply making it a UV wrap. So, all is provided out-of-the-box, including the hardware acceleration, but the biggest downside is that the result is highly distorted because contents of the polygons are separate from each other. For example, having a 2-poly rect and moving one of its vertices so that one of the polys is significantly reduced and the other one is still at its full, creates strong distortions...

Comment: So you'd prefer an interpolation that is not linear, but rather "skewed" to keep the internal as similar as possible and have bigger adjustments near the edges, I presume.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10966129/864696